# WSO2 : Which Message Transformation Mediator?

Tags: xslt, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have some scenario for message transformation in ESB. i want to know which message transformation mediator (XSLT, Enrich, Payload Factory) is a suitable and common for each of these scenario?

1- Changing the data type of one or more field of a message

2- Deleting one or more field of a message

3- Adding one or more new field to a message

4- Changing the name of one or more field of a message

5- Changing the order of a message's fields

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT mediator provides you a lot of flexibility on transforming messages over the other mediators. So, you can certainly do this using the XSLT mediator. As I see, you can achieve the scenarios 2-5 using payload mediator as well quite easily. I'm not sure what you meant in the first scenario though.

Comment: thanks for your answer. an example for scenario 1 is converting a float or double value to int value.

Comment: I want to perform these transformation in a dynamic way. so what is your proposal now?

Comment: Payload factory mediator doesn't offer much dynamism. So, I guess using XSLT mediator seems better. scenario 1 can be done using the xpath functions. So, afaik both these mediators can perform step 1.